# Omit front page in Bartik theme

Tags: redirection

Hey I am using the Empty Front Page module https://drupal.org/project/empty_front_page on a sub-theme(Bartik) but the problem is that when I open my domain I see an empty screen and none of the tabs are open. Can I somehow omit this empty page and direct the user to the home tab of the website meaning www.example.com to example.com/home?

PS: I am new to php and Drupal!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? You can change the default home page under "Admin -> Configuration -> System -> Site information".

Comment: Danke berliner!

Answer (score 0):

I will present a solution for empty front page here with help of [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module.

You can create or use a content type which you are not intended to use. Either you can create one or use `article` etc.

Create a views with selecting that content type & set other things such as `no pager` & `0 posts`, so that this views doesn't produce any result.

Give it a name such as `home` & make a page with same name.

Go to your **site configuration** & set this `home` as `front page` path. You are done.